# Prevent error_log from being accessible from the web using root .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm hosting my PHP site on a shared web hosting service. I need to prevent `error_log` files from being accessible from the public web via an HTTP request.

The current solution that I found is to add the following lines to the `.htaccess` files that must be placed into *each* directory where `error_log` files are located:

```
<files error_log>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</files>
```

It works, but I'm curious if there a solution to do this from the `.htaccess` in the root directory?

Comment: Why would you store your error logs under a web accessible directory in the first place?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Good point. What shall I do to move it to a "better" location?

Comment: Simply move the files out of your web root and then configure your host/virtual host in apache to point the error logs to the new location

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: I'm not sure if I can access apache configuration. I'm hosting on a shared service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^|/)error_log$ - [L,R=404]
```

Or replace the flags with `[L,F]` if you prefer a 403 Forbidden response instead of a 404 not found.